# Generate interval date from array

Tags: php

I have two dates (start and end), for example:

```
$date['start'] = '2012-07-11';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-13';
```

i would like generate -4 and +4 days interval for this. So i would like receive for example array  with:

```
$date['start'] = '2012-07-07';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-09';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-08';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-10';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-09';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-11';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-10';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-12';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-11';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-13';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-12';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-14';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-13';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-15';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-14';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-16';

$date['start'] = '2012-07-15';
$date['end'] = '2012-07-17';
```

How is the best way for this?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see a question here. SO is not really a service that writes your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the trick:

```
 $date['start'] = '2012-07-11';
 $date['end'] = '2012-07-13';

 $dates=array();
 for ($i=-4; $i<=4; $i++){
   $startDate=strtotime($date['start'] );
   $endDate=strtotime($date['end'] );

   $startDate=$startDate+($i*60*60*24); //60*60*24 equal to one day
   $endDate=$endDate+($i*60*60*24);

   array_push($dates, array('start'=>date('Y-m-d', $startDate), 'end'=> date('Y-m-d',$endDate)));
 }
 print_r($dates);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-07
            [end] => 2012-07-09
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-08
            [end] => 2012-07-10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-09
            [end] => 2012-07-11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-10
            [end] => 2012-07-12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-11
            [end] => 2012-07-13
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-12
            [end] => 2012-07-14
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-13
            [end] => 2012-07-15
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-14
            [end] => 2012-07-16
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-07-15
            [end] => 2012-07-17
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

range(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-4 days'), date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+4 days'))),

Comment: this return me "Array ( [0] => 2 ) "

Answer (score 0):

You want 9 pairs of dates starting from -4 days of the supplied range, upto +4 days?

Assuming that your dates will be after 1970:

```
<?php
$start=strtotime($date['start']);
$end=strtotime($date['end']);

for($loop=-4;$loop<=4;$loop++)
{
    $loop_str='';
    if($loop>=0) $loop_str.='+';
    $loop_str.=$loop.' days';
    $date['start']=strtotime($loop_str, $start);
    $date['end']=strtotime($loop_str, $end);
    print_r($date);
}
?>
```